# How do I make sshfs work in Debian? (I get /dev/fuse: Permission denied )

Tags: ssh, debian, sshfs, fuse

I've moved from Ubuntu to Debian on a machine and all my sshfs mounting scripts fail with

```
fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied
```

now.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For some reason, Debian configures FUSE to require users to be in the `fuse` group.

Run `gpasswd -a username fuse` as root, then log out and **log in again**. (Important step.)

Comment: just for record - this did not work for me :-(

Comment: I am not an expert but I solved my problem by changing permissions of /dev/fuse - it had a root group and not rw for group (sudo chgrp fuse /dev/fuse; sudo chmod g+w /dev/fuse)

Comment: I have two Wheezy... one installed from scratch, another which was upgrade from Squeeze and then installed fuse later... and I have different permission on /dev/fuse. A recent bug in fuse package ?

Comment: Didn't work for me, neither did changing the group and setting permissions on /dev/fuse.

Comment: Can be : usermod -aG fuse <your-username>
as root, then log out and log in again

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the same thing, (except `gpasswd` also has a "remove" option so it's generally more convenient to do group changes with).

Comment: You don't have to logout/login, just type 'newgrp fuse'.

Comment: @DmitrySandalov: That works, but only for the particular terminal window.

Comment: This fails for me with this error: `gpasswd: group 'fuse' does not exist in /etc/group`

Answer (score 12):

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=617667) indicating that Debian Wheezy (which seems to have the version 2.9.0-2 of the fuse package, the bug is reported fixed in 2.9.0-3) may set wrong permissions for `/dev/fuse` (`crw------T 1 root root` in my case).

As stated around the comments of the earlier posts, this can be fixed by running the following commands as root:

```
chmod g+rw /dev/fuse
chgrp fuse /dev/fuse
```

Also remember to add your user to the `fuse` group with, e.g., `gpasswd -a username fuse`.

Answer (score 2):

Changing permissions ('sudo chmod g+rw /dev/fuse', the above omits the 'r') did work for me (in addition of course to adding my user to the fuse group).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same /dev/fuse permission denied problem (unrelated the sshfs).  In my case the [fuse](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=fuse) package was not installed.  The package provides all the basic necessities like the mount tools, sysfs control, a new "fuse" group, and inode permission (managed by udev).

```
# apt-get install fuse
# usermod -a -G fuse <username>
# modprobe fuse
```

Last command loads the kernel module, and the kernel tells udev to set the permissions.

Comment: `usermod -G fuse <username>` useradd does not accept the -a parameter

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.  Turned out the permission for /dev/fuse was the following.  I did the chmod command and it works fine.  Don't know how it got into this state. It was working yesterday.

```
$ ls -l /dev/fuse
crw-rw---T 1 root fuse 10, 229 May  4 16:41 /dev/fuse

chmod a+rw /dev/fuse

#now it works fine!
```

Comment: The reason the `fuse` group exists is so that administrators can control who can use FUSE to mount filesystems: only those who are in the `fuse` group (or have root access) can use FUSE. Your solution gives access to all users.